# ¿Como consumir un api Rest de Tookan?

Tags: c#, .net, api, rest

buenas tardes, soy un poco nuevo en el cosumo de API´s Rest, necesito consumir la siguiente api: https://api.tookanapp.com, leyendo la documentación por lo que entendí es para realizar metodos POST, no se como hacer para lograr consumirla mediante GET, utilizo una aplicación de consola en C#, mi código es el siguiente:

//Get method

```
        WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(@"https://api.tookanapp.com");

        req.Method = "GET";

        HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            using (Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Status Code: {0}, Status Description: {1}", resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusDescription));
        }
        Console.Read();
```

al final del dia me manda un error 404, supongo porque no alcanza el servidor....

Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: porque en lugar de intentar primero consumirla desde codigo no lo haces desde una tool usando por ejemplo postman https://www.getpostman.com/ asi sabras como debes enviar los datos para obtener la repsuesta, es mas esa tool depsues te muestra un codigo de ejemplo que podrias usar

Comment: intentaste abrir la url en el browser, te dice "Cannot GET / ", como que lo deja bien claro

Comment: que tal, he seguido tus posteos y me haz sacado de muchos apuros, en fin, te comento, jamas habia hecho este tipo de desarrollos, y no sabia que existia este tipo de herramientas, gracias por el aporte...

Answer (score 0):

Si analizamos la documentacion de la libreria

[Tookan API](https://tookanapi.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/task-statuses)

observaras que menciona que la url `https://api.tookanapp.com` es la url base desde la cual debes definir que acciones vas a realizar, por ejemplo menciona `https://api.tookanapp.com/v2/create_task` para crear una task

Ademas necesitas tener una `api key` para poder acceder a la funcionalidad, lo menciona en la documentacion

> Tookan API uses key based authentication method. You can get a key from settings(Login>Menu>Settings>API Keys) in your tookan account

para lo cual necesitas tener una cuenta

Analizando los error code hace referencia que un 404 es:

```
404 -- ERROR_IN_EXECUTION
```

Por ejemplo si accedes a:
https://tookanapi.docs.apiary.io/#reference/task/view-all-tasks/view-all-tasks

veras que al url de la api para obtener la lista de task es: https://api.tookanapp.com/v2/get_all_tasks

y esta se invoca como POST

Sobre la derecha tienes una ventana que muestra un ejemplo con codigo c# de como implementa rla invocacion a la api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recomiendo que analices mejor la documentacion porque esta muy completa y uses la clase `HttpClient` para invocar la API

Comment: Muchas gracias Leandro, me sirve mucho tus comentarios...
Comenzare mis pruebas y compartire el resultado...
Slds..